# Xcode 5 C++ SDL app not loading outside of XCode IDE

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, sdl, sdl-2

I've been coding a game for the past year, I'm in the process of porting to Mac.

I've set everything up according to: http://blog.davidecoppola.com/2013/08/22/how-to-set-up-a-sdl-2-project-for-os-x-in-xcode-4/. I have changed some of the steps to compensate for the version (5).

In my code I use tinyXML to load a .xml file within an assets folder. This works perfectly on windows and linux, however, in Mac I experience some issues. Here's the line:

```
Doc.LoadFile(DataPath);
```

Doc is a tinyxml2::XMLDocument type, and the DataPath is usually "assets/Data.xml", in Mac I hard-coded that line into the place of "DataPath".

When running the code within the IDE I experience no issues and my game comes up and plays like it does on all other platforms, however, when running the .app file (Located in gameMac/Build/Products/Debug) it crashes right after starting up. The Assets folder is also located in this location.

Here's the error Mac throws at me after the crash:

```
Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   gameMac                        0x000c1525 tinyxml2::XMLNode::FirstChildElement(char const*) const + 21
1   gameMac                        0x000d1954 tinyxml2::XMLNode::FirstChildElement(char const*) + 36
2   gameMac                        0x000d04d5 DataLoader::load(char const*, ID_Data, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >) + 197
3   gameMac                        0x000a5849 MapHandler::MapHandler(std::__1::shared_ptr<gameData>) + 1177
4   gameMac                        0x000a539e MapHandler::MapHandler(std::__1::shared_ptr<gameData>) + 30
5   gameMac                        0x000b7eb8 splay::splay(std::__1::shared_ptr<gameData>) + 1592
6   gameMac                        0x000b786e splay::splay(std::__1::shared_ptr<gameData>) + 30
7   gameMac                        0x000ee3f9 std::__1::shared_ptr<splay> std::__1::shared_ptr<splay>::make_shared<std::__1::shared_ptr<gameData>&>(std::__1::shared_ptr<gameData>&&&) + 1849
8   gameMac                        0x000ebc7c stateHandlerGen::stateHandlerGen(std::__1::shared_ptr<gameData>) + 236
9   gameMac                        0x000ebb7e stateHandlerGen::stateHandlerGen(std::__1::shared_ptr<gameData>) + 30
10  gameMac                        0x000e7a89 game::init(char const*, int, int, int, int, bool) + 1545
11  gameMac                        0x000be8c4 main + 516
12  libdyld.dylib                       0x91b3c725 start + 1
```

(Please note that gameMac is not the name of my project, I have changed that detail due to an NDA).

As I've noted here, the same method that loads my data `DataLoader::load(params)` is giving the crash. This leads me to believe that my assets folder is not being loaded into my .app file.

Through this I attempted to edit a Build Phase, `Copy Bundle Resources` this did not change the issue. I then attempted to make a New Build Phase `Copy Files` and set it to `Resources`, this also failed. I then experimented by setting the `Copy Files` to `Product Directory`; this copied the assets folder to the build folder, but the .app file still won't load in the assets.

Did I miss something? Could some XCode vets help me out here, I've attempted to fix this for the past few days. Thanks.

http://pastebin.com/Xq4Hxh4d (Here's the top of my DataLoader as mentioned above. EDIT: Added in my check for nullptr return, yes, it returns true if failed).

P.S I can only give out snippets of my code, I have given what I feel is most likely the problem, resource loading :)

The full crash report is in the comments below.

The fix, thanks to the help from Brad Allred:

The resources are located within the .app file, specifically {Application}/Contents/Resources ; in my case I wanted to access a file within assets. I did a build phase to copy the data to the resources folder, making my directory {Application}/Contents/Resources/Assets/../. Using SDL_GetBasePath I'm able to create a string which is the absolute path from your base directory up to the Resources folder.

Here's the code:

```
if(Doc.LoadFile("assets/Data.xml"))
{
    std::string path = (std::string)SDL_GetBasePath() + "assets/Data.xml";
    if(Doc.LoadFile(path.c_str()))
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

I concat the base path + whatever data I need, and pass the .c_str() version to tinyXML. If I find a better/cleaner version I'll be sure to update it here.

Comment: Are you trying to load a file, and don't check for a `NULL` pointer return? The reason that might happen is because the current directory when you run it in Xcode might be another from where you run the program outside Xcode.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg The pastebin snippet is a bit older than the current version. I haven't updated my repository. I do check for nullptr return, all works fine inside the IDE. If that is so, then how do I go about linking my assets folder to my application file? EDIT: I added in my nullptr check.

Comment: having the *complete* crash report (or at least the `Exception Type`) and the console output would be useful.

Comment: @BradAllred Here's the full crash report: http://pastebin.com/Hc3m3XGX

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your [crash report](http://pastebin.com/Hc3m3XGX) tells you the line number in your code that is crashing (`tinyxml2.cpp:745`).  at Probably your assets are not where the app expects them to be or doesnt have permission. examining your `DataPath` to see where its trying to load should get you started.

It seems like maybe you are mistakenly assuming that you can use a relative path and get assets relative to the app bundle; you can't do that.

Since you are using SDL, why not use the SDL API (see [SDL_GetBasePath](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_GetBasePath)) to get resource paths so that you can store your assets properly *inside* your app bundle in the Resources directory?

Comment: Where does the app expect my assets to be? I put them right next to the app launcher, should they be inside the app file itself? Tinyxml 2 is a free, little API found online. It's trying to access elements which isn't there due to not being able to load the assets folder.

Comment: @creativeflow why are you asking me where *your* app expects your assets to be? as I stated you can inspect your `DataPath` variable with your debugger to see where its trying to load from. I'm also updating my answer with some hopefully useful information

Comment: Damn, I should have checked for something to give me the directory. Thank you very much, got it working neatly. I already had the data inside the resource folder, but could not get to it from inside the code without giving a full path. Thanks a lot! If I could upvote, I would.

Comment: @creativeflow glad you solved it. This is actually a fairly common issue for people unfamiliar with the concept of application bundles.

Comment: I'm glad you got on here to help my sorry ass! Thank you, again. It's been quite a few days and a bit of sleep deprivation; checking the sdl library is usually the first thing I do, but the whole Mac thing threw me off. Hopefully my post can lead to some help for future participants.